# Read PNG Thumbnail from MediaLibrary

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-8, bitmapimage

i'm read a Pictures from Albums into a MediaLibrary of my device.
If in a album i have a PNG not show preview

this is my code (works with JPG)

```
 Picture pic = value as Picture;
 BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
 image.SetSource(pic.GetThumbnail());
 return image;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet. Didn't you use the `MediaLibrary` class?

```
MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();

        foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
        {
            Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();

            var imageToShow = new Image()
            {
                Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(r.GetImage())
            };

            yourlistboxname.Items.Add(imageToShow);
        }
    }
```

Have a look over [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx)

Comment: i use ItemsSource, how to?

Comment: @JohnBrush are you binding the template to any listbox or any other control?

Comment: but how are you displaying the image which you've binded within the data template? I Cannot see anyway of displaying the image? Where is your ItemsSource?

Comment: so the code should work fine. but you said it doesn't work with png files isn't it?

Comment: yes. my code works but not with PNG format file. I can adapt my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55783/discussion-between-john-brush-and-anonshankar).